# How can I make my R Shiny Dashboard fill the entire Page?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have an R Shiny app that I'm making using `shinydashboard`, but I'm having a problem getting the UI to fill the browser window.

Here is my ui.R output:

```
#
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application. You can
# run the application by clicking 'Run App' above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
# 
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

## app.R ##
library(rsconnect)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

#shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(height = 1080))


ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Miradashboard",
                  # This drop-down menu offers user and system administration within the application
                  dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                               messageItem(
                                 from = "Sales Dept",
                                 message = "Sales are steady this month."
                               ),
                               messageItem(
                                 from = "New User",
                                 message = "How do I register?",
                                 icon = icon("question"),
                                 time = "13:45"
                               ),
                               messageItem(
                                 from = "Support",
                                 message = "The new server is ready.",
                                 icon = icon("life-ring"),
                                 time = "2014-12-01"
                               )
                  ),
                  # This is a drop-down menu for checking notifications.
                  # This should alert users of alerts that have not been merged to a case in the last 15 days.
                  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                               notificationItem(
                                 text = "5 new users today",
                                 icon("users")
                               ),
                               notificationItem(
                                 text = "12 items delivered",
                                 icon("truck"),
                                 status = "success"
                               ),
                               notificationItem(
                                 text = "Server load at 86%",
                                 icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                                 status = "warning"
                               )
                  ),
                  # This is a drop-down menu for checking tasks.
                  # This drop-down menu will eventually offer suggestions based off of ML Algorithms.
                  dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "success",
                               taskItem(value = 90, color = "green",
                                        "Documentation"
                               ),
                               taskItem(value = 17, color = "aqua",
                                        "Project X"
                               ),
                               taskItem(value = 75, color = "yellow",
                                        "Server deployment"
                               ),
                               taskItem(value = 80, color = "red",
                                        "Overall project"
                               )
                  )



  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    ## Sidebar content
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
        menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")),
        menuItem("Reports", tabName = "reports", icon = icon("th")),
        menuItem("OpsCare Clients", tabName = "OpsCare Clients", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
        menuItem("ProdCare Clients", tabName = "ProdCare Clients", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
        menuItem("Alerts", tabName = "Alerts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
        menuItem("Change Requests", tabName = "Change Requests", icon = icon("list-alt")),
        menuItem("Maintenance Windows", tabName = "Maintenance Windows", icon = icon("list-alt")),
        menuItem("Rundeck", tabName = "Rundeck", icon = icon("bars")),
        menuItem("Salesforce", tabName = "Salesforce", icon = icon("bars")),
        menuItem("Handovers", tabName = "Handovers", icon = icon("bars")),
        menuItem("Jump-Host Access", tabName = "Jump-Host Access", icon = icon("bars"))
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      box(plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)),
      box(plotOutput("plot3", height = 250)),
      #box(plotOutput("plot4", height = 250)),
      #box(dataTableOutput("DT1", height = 250)),
      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  # List Server Output whereby plot[1-#] is the plot box output in UI above.
  # Server Output occurds and is defined by data variables
  # histdata[seq_len(input$slider)] defines slider utilization
  # hist(data) defines histogram off of "data"te
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  output$plot5 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see in the attached a picture, the page is being cut off in a Web Browser. My eventual goal would be to extend it to the full screen as I am trying to make this available and accessible for internal users. If anyone has any suggestions in terms of how to extend the dashboard page to full size that would be nice.

In terms of trying to solve it on my own I have looked into the following aspects to extend it to full screen.

1. I looked at shiny.js but this does not seem to be a standard repoistory or installation through CRAN
2. I looked at the fillPage functionality, but this makes it HTML and the above code is not in HTML format
3. I have looked at invoking the Fill page functionality, but it has not done so within the full page view within a web-browser. The invoked command was placed before ad after the ui <- dashboardPage definition within the ui.R

[image: Screenshot showing UI being cut halfway down the window]

Comment: I've added the picture for you, but you should know that you can [edit] your question by clicking the edit button below the tag list. To make it easy to read, changes or clarifications should be done by editing the body of the question, not by posting things in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @divibisan I am pretty new to working inside of this community so I am still trying to learn the ins and outs :D

Comment: No worries! I assume you've tried looking other browsers outside of the RStudio browser (which often does weird things)? Also, can you scroll the cut off window to see all the content?

Comment: Have you tried running it in an external browser (not in the RStudio viewer pane)? On my system the full page is displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code and it's displayed fullscreen. Here the app on my [shinyapp.io account](https://abenedetti.shinyapps.io/test/).

Maybe you'll have to check the application version. Here's the packages versions I have. I'm on R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) and RStudio 1.1.463.

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

other attached packages:
 [1] shinydashboard_0.7.1     shinydashboardPlus_0.6.0 rsconnect_0.8.12        
 [4] shiny_1.2.0              forcats_0.3.0            stringr_1.3.1           
 [7] dplyr_0.7.5              purrr_0.2.4              readr_1.1.1             
[10] tidyr_0.8.1              tibble_1.4.2             ggplot2_3.0.0           
[13] tidyverse_1.2.1         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.4 reshape2_1.4.3   haven_1.1.1      lattice_0.20-38 
 [5] colorspace_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.2.0       utf8_1.1.4      
 [9] rlang_0.2.0      pillar_1.2.3     later_0.7.5      foreign_0.8-71  
[13] glue_1.3.0       withr_2.1.2      modelr_0.1.2     readxl_1.1.0    
[17] bindrcpp_0.2.2   bindr_0.1.1      plyr_1.8.4       munsell_0.4.3   
[21] gtable_0.2.0     cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_0.3.2      psych_1.8.4     
[25] httpuv_1.4.5.1   parallel_3.5.2   broom_0.4.4      Rcpp_1.0.0      
[29] xtable_1.8-2     openssl_1.0.1    promises_1.0.1   scales_0.5.0    
[33] jsonlite_1.6     mime_0.5         mnormt_1.5-5     hms_0.4.2       
[37] digest_0.6.18    stringi_1.1.7    grid_3.5.2       cli_1.0.0       
[41] tools_3.5.2      magrittr_1.5     lazyeval_0.2.1   crayon_1.3.4    
[45] pkgconfig_2.0.1  xml2_1.2.0       lubridate_1.7.4  assertthat_0.2.0
[49] httr_1.3.1       rstudioapi_0.7   R6_2.2.2         nlme_3.1-137    
[53] compiler_3.5.2
```

I've also tried "Run in Window" in RStudio and it worked fullscreen as well.

[image]

Comment: I finally got some time to devote to this project again, as I am the only making any work on it. But yeah it turns out my packages were out of date.

Comment: This only works for the ui.R and server.R in a single application, not for the Shiny Application that is using both ui.R and server.R separately.